# MYSQL count Query error

Tags: mysql

Mysql Query:

```
SELECT `message`.`id` as `message_id`, 
`pet_info`.`id` as `pet_id`,
`pet_info`.`pet_hidenum` as `hidenum`,
`lostpets`.`pet_lost_date` as `pet_lost_date`,
`lostpets`.`type` as `status`,
`pet_images`.`img` as `img`,
COUNT(SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `message`.`status` = 'not seen') as unread 
 FROM `message`
 LEFT JOIN `pet_info` ON `pet_info`.`id` = `message`.`pet_id`
 LEFT JOIN `pet_images` ON `pet_images`.`petid` = `message`.`pet_id`
 LEFT JOIN `lostpets` ON `lostpets`.`petid` = `message`.`pet_id`
```

Error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `message`.`status` = 'not seen') as unread FROM `m' at line 1
```

Please help me where is an error in this query? and How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Post the error stack.

Comment: @AbdullahWasi Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you intended, but for the error, you want to apply the count function inside the subquery:

```
select message.id as message_id,
    pet_info.id as pet_id,
    pet_info.pet_hidenum as hidenum,
    lostpets.pet_lost_date as pet_lost_date,
    lostpets.type as status,
    pet_images.img as img,
    (
        select COUNT(*)
        from message
        where message.status = 'not seen'
        ) as unread
from message
left join pet_info on pet_info.id = message.pet_id
left join pet_images on pet_images.petid = message.pet_id
left join lostpets on lostpets.petid = message.pet_id
```

Also try to not use backticks by using standard aliases and identifier names because the backticks hinder readability.

If that's not what you want, please edit your question and add sample data and expected output.